# Android graph view

Tags: android, graph, android-canvas, android-graphview

I have used jjoe64's graphview  library to implement graph in my app. It has pretty good samples inside the box and started right away to include it in my app. Wat i have got so far is as shown below.

[image]

But what i actually need is as shown below, I dont want that dark vertical lines to come inside the graph. Any idea how to remove these vertical lines. Also i wanted to add the markers at each graph points. The markers are usually png's. And the last, i wanted the change the vertical label sizes. Can somebody help me out with this. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: in the current version you can change the labels text size

Comment: @jjoe64 Thanks for the reply. I will give it a try. Also I wanted to animate the graph while adding a new series to it.(i.e  after doing this - graphSeries.appendData(newGraphData)) Can you give me a clue about how doing that.?

Answer (score 2):

You can use achartengine for more effective customization. It is the most popular free graphview library for Android.You can find latest version and tutorials here http://www.achartengine.org/