# GraphView label font size and spacing

Tags: android, android-graphview

[Add space between graph and tick labels in GraphView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183486/add-space-between-graph-and-tick-labels-in-graphview) answers how to add a space between the graph and axis labels

[Android graph view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133110/android-graph-view) has an answer which says it is possible to change the font size of axis labels.

However it seems those functionalities have been removed. are there any plans to reinstate them? Alternatively, are there currently ways to change the font size and spacing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I change the label's text size in this way:

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setTextSize(6f);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().reloadStyles();
```

Comment: `graph.getGridLabelRenderer().reloadStyles();` also fixed my GridColor not updating issue after calling `graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridColor();`  Big Thanks!